# How can I extract the points from a ListSurfacePlot3D?

Tags: graphics

How can I get numerical output of ListSurfacePlot3D, i.e., a list of all the points, $(x,y,z)$ , used to construct the plot?

Thanks to your help I now have a list of (x,y,z). But the new mesh is irregular, I need z-values on specific (x,y). In more detail:

The original data (https://www.dropbox.com/s/q76qsrf8hl4li7g/6686.dat) is an array of 40 by 40, with

> x = {0, 0.5, 1.0, ..., 19.5}

and the same for y.

Following user0501's suggestion the output is:

> data = {{0., 8.73992, 14.8593}, {0., 8.38421, 15.075}, {0., 8.3125, 
>     15.1281}, {0., 8.22328, 15.1943}, {0., 7.77126, 15.5292}, {0., 
>     7.31923, 15.8642}, {0., 7.125, 16.0081},...}

How can I get the result based on the same regular grid as the grid based on the input data?

If you like, you can get the original data here:

```
data = Import["https://dl.dropbox.com/s/q76qsrf8hl4li7g/6686.dat"];
surf = ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 5]
```

Again, thanks a lot for your help!!

Harald

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
p = ListSurfacePlot3D[Flatten[
       Table[{Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, -π, π, .2}, {θ, 0, π, .2}], 1]]
Graphics3D@Line@Cases[Normal[p], Line[x__] :> x, ∞]
Graphics3D@
 Point@Flatten[Cases[Normal[p], Line[x__] :> x, ∞], 1]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Flatten[Cases[Normal[p], Line[x__] :> x, ∞], 1]
```

should give you the list of x,y,z.

Comment: yes, this is exactly I was looking for. Thanks a lot, Harald

Comment: May I ask an additional question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your new question, but if you want to group the points, you can do something like `SplitBy[data, {First, Part[#, 2] &}]`, if you want to sort, you can do something like `SortBy[data, {First, Part[#, 2] &}]`.

Comment: I need the z-values of Flatten[Cases[Normal[p], Line[x__] :> x, ∞],1] at grid-positions at (0, 0), (0, 0.5),...(0, 19.5), (0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1),..., (19.5, 19.5). So I wonder wether it would be possible to extract the data at these positions. Again, thanks for your effort, Harald

Comment: Can you put your code which generate `data` into the question? Since it's a surface plot, I guess I don't think you have z values on every point of the grid.

Comment: yes, I did it. By the way: The data are not generated, they are the results of a resistivity survey within an 20 m by 20 m grid

Comment: I think ListSurfacePlot3D generates points that are not necessary correspond to every point on the grid, so you may not expect to get all the points. What are you trying to achieve by obtaining the data from ListSurfacePlot3D? If you just want to smooth the points, or fit them to some model, I would recommend have a look at `Fit` and `Interpolation` and functions in [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DataTransformsAndSmoothing.html).

Comment: This was indeed my intention: extracting a two-dimensional trend. Because I have some dozens of such data files, I thought I could do it in this way...