# How do I get the co-ordinates of the spheres from the output of this code?

Tags: graphics3d

```
noa = 16; theta = -2 Pi/(noa); radius = 0.3; n = noa/2;

h = Sqrt[3]; vA = {1, -h, 0}; vF = {-1, -h, 0};

x = Cos[theta]; z = Sin[theta]; sA = Sphere[vA, radius]; 
sF = Sphere[vF, radius]; 
atoms = Table[Subscript[m, i], {i, n}];
atoms[[1]] = {sA, sF};

Do[atoms[[i]] = Rotate[Translate[atoms[[i - 1]], {x + 2, ((-1)^i)*h, -z}], -2*theta, 
                       {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}],
   {i, 2, n}];
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[atoms, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {xaxis, yaxis, zaxis}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need to generate the coordinates from the output, since you have the input coordinates already, since you used them to generate the spheres?

Comment: This was just an example. I need the coordinates so I could use them in other plotting tools.

Comment: I have edited my question. I don't have the coordinates to all of the spheres. Just two of them. I generate the others. So how do I get the coordinates from the generated spheres.

Comment: The answer is ok, just add `Normal` like in this duplicate: [23637](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23637/5478)

Answer (score 3):

Given the figure as a Mathematica object, you can obtain the code that produced it by using,

```
% // InputForm
```

Better, as suggested by Kuba, is

```
ReleaseHold[Cases[Normal[ans2 // InputForm], Sphere[z__, _] -> HoldForm[z], Infinity]]
```

which give  just a `List` of the locations without other information.  A part of the rather long output is

```
{{1, -Sqrt[3], 0}, {-1, -Sqrt[3], 0}, 
 {1/Sqrt[2] + (2 - Sqrt[2])/2 + (2 + Cos[Pi/8])/Sqrt[2] + 
    Sin[Pi/8]/Sqrt[2], 0, -((2 + Cos[Pi/8])/Sqrt[2]) + Sin[Pi/8]/Sqrt[2]}, 
 {-(1/Sqrt[2]) + (2 - Sqrt[2])/2 + (2 + Cos[Pi/8])/Sqrt[2] + 
    Sin[Pi/8]/Sqrt[2], 0, Sqrt[2] - (2 + Cos[Pi/8])/Sqrt[2] + Sin[Pi/8]/Sqrt[2]}, ...}
```

Enclose the result in `N` to obtain a compact result.

```
{{1., -1.7320508075688772, 0.}, 
 {-1., -1.7320508075688772, 0.}, 
 {3.338093094884382, 0., -1.7968969947381848}, 
 {1.923879532511287, 0., -0.3826834323650896}, 
 {3.7207765272494715, -1.7320508075688772, -4.7207765272494715}, 
 {3.7207765272494715, -1.7320508075688772, -2.7207765272494715}, 
 {1.9238795325112865, 0., -7.058869622133854}, 
 {3.338093094884382, 0., -5.6446560597607585}, 
 {-0.9999999999999999, -1.7320508075688772, -7.441553054498944}, 
 {0.9999999999999999, -1.7320508075688772, -7.441553054498944}, 
 {-3.3380930948843814, 0., -5.644656059760759}, 
 {-1.9238795325112865, 0., -7.058869622133854}, 
 {-3.720776527249471, -1.7320508075688772, -2.720776527249472}, 
 {-3.720776527249471, -1.7320508075688772, -4.7207765272494715}, 
 {-1.9238795325112865, 0., -0.3826834323650897}, 
 {-3.3380930948843814, 0., -1.7968969947381845}}
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thank you. I need these coordinates as a text file so I can use other plotting tools as well. How do I do that? I have a code which generates many spheres, I don't have a gif image.

Comment: This works for the previous example but doesn't work for what I have. I have edited my question and put exactly what I need. I'm extremely sorry, I should have put this instead of another example.

Comment: Add `Normal` inside `Cases`.

Comment: @Kuba Beautiful.  I did not know that Normal had such power.  Please create an Answer based on this.  Alternatively, I can revise my Answer, credit you, and flag it as a community wiki answer.  Your call.

Comment: @Kuba and bbgodfrey Thank you man!! :)

Comment: @ransell No problem, good luck. Take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) meanwhile :)

Comment: Thank you :). This is exactly what i was looking for! Going thru the tour right now